# Rcpp with Rmarkdown? Error while compilying

Tags: r, r-markdown, rcpp

I want to create a html document with Rmarkdown. At the beginning of a R code I need to source few R scripts, while one of them contains definition of C++ function wrote with `Rcpp`. A chunk of code in Rmd runs succesfully, but while knitting I'm getting an error:

> Line 85 Error in command 'sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, cacheDir = cacheDir, ': Error 1 occurred building shared library. Calls:  ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> cppFunction -> sourceCpp

Unfortunetely, I can't share my whole code but it is structured like below. Anyway, it seems that the error is caused by using `cppFunction`. How can I handle this to produce html or pdf document?

````
```{r}
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)
library(Rcpp)

source('directory\\script1.R')
source('directory\\script2.R')
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the knitr documentation -- Rcpp is actually a proper processor. So you can do

````
```{Rcpp firstChunk}
Rcpp::IntegerVector doubleMe(Rcpp::IntegerVector x) {
  return x + x;
}
```
````

followed by

````
```{r secondChunk}
myvector <- 19:21
cat("The answer is ", tail(doubleMe(myvector), 1), "\n")
```
````

and it will do the right thing.  You can formally depend on the first chunk in the second chunk and more -- see the knitr docs.

Comment: For some reasons I don't understand, I need `Rcpp` instead of `rcpp` for the language used in the Rmd chunk.